# Div display:none escondendo o restante do código após ela

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho o seguinte **código**:

```
  $htmlPDF = $html;

  $html .= '
      <div style="display:none;" id="conteudoHTML">' . $htmlPDF . '</div>
      <button type="button" class="button" onclick="createPDF();">pdf</button>
    <form action="pdf.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="htmlPDF" value="' . $htmlPDF . '</div>" />
      <input type="submit" class="button formularios" value="Gerar PDF" >
    </form><br /><br />
    <button id="btnGrafico" class="button formularios">Gerar Gráfico</button><br />
    <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>
  ';
```

Por que é que se eu fizer **display: none** na **div#conteudoHTML**, o resto do `código` não roda?

Nem os **buttons**, nem o **form** e nem o **canvas**

Conteúdo da variável **$htmlDF** e o **CSS**:

```css
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
    }
    html, body {
        min-height:100%
    }
    html {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 1em;
        background-image: radial-gradient(rgb(172,204,193) 20%, rgb(40, 22, 111));
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    a, a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    select {
     box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    
    textarea {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 8px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    img.voltar {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .divMensagem {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .menu {
     width: auto;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .textoPrincipal, .sucesso, .erro {
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     line-height: 300px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .erro, .hCentralizadoAvisos {
     color: rgb(255,0,0);
    }
    .hCentralizado, .hCentralizadoAvisos, .erro {
     width: auto;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .formularios {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    .labelPequeno {
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .labelMinimo {
     display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px;
     width:100px;
    }
    .labelMini {
     display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px;
     width:50px;
    }
    .inputTextMedio {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .button {
        width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 3px;
    }
    .btnAcesso, .btnPesquisa {
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        width: 208px;
        height: 44px;
    }
    .btnAcesso {
        background-image: url(../../_imgs/acesso.png);
    }
    .btnPesquisa {
        background-image: url(../../_imgs/pesquisar.png);
    }
    .modelos {
        color: red;
    }
    .todo {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }
    .topo, .cont, .final {
        display: block;
    }
    .cont {
     min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    }
    .final {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .finalEsquerda, .finalDireita {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .finalEsquerda {
        width: 78%;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .finalDireita {
        width: 20%;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: right;
    }
    
    /*///////////////////////// INICIO LISTAGENS ///////////////*/
    div.lista {
        margin: auto;
    }
    ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros, ul.listaFuncoes, ul.menuItens {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul.listaTopo {
     background-color: rgb(217,217,217);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
    ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li, ul.listaFuncoes li {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    ul.menuItens li {
        width: 22%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    /*///////////////////////// FIM LISTAGENS /////////////////*/
    
    div.relatorio {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.relatorio .centralizado {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    div.relatorio .backCinza {
        background-color: rgb(217,217,217);
    }
    div.relatorio ul.detalhes {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.lancamento li, div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 18px;
        font-size: .85em;
        border-left: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.lancamento li {
        width: 113.5px !important;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
        width: 150px !important;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.lancamento li:first-child, div.relatorio ul.resumo li:first-child {
        border-left: none;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.ulInlineBlock li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    div.relatorio ul.border {
        border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    }
    span.vertical {
     -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
         -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
             writing-mode: vertical-lr;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
             transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    span.comum {  
    
    }
    div.cabecalhoVertical{
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
     width: 800px;
     height: 220px;
     border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    
    }
    div.cabecalhoVertical div {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
         -ms-flex-align: center;
             align-items: center;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
         -ms-flex-pack: center;
             justify-content: center;
    }
    div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bolder;
    }
```

```html
<div class='relatorio'> 
<img src='http://www.wesleyanagceu.com.br/_imgs/gceu.png' /> <h1>Relatório Mensal</h1> 
<br><br>  
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangelismo</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>     
</div> 
<div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Célula 1</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Cleonice</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>50</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>13</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>73</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>22,65</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>2</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>11</span></div>
</div>    
<div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula 2</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>5</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>18</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>78,39</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>     
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>1</span></div>
</div>    
<div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula TOP</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
 <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
</div>    
<div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jesuita</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
 <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
</div>    
<div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Tassito</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
 <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wv2jnydp/

Comment: 99% de certeza que o problema está no conteúdo de `$htmlPDF`.

Answer (score 1):

Ao utilizar o `display: none` você faz com que elemento (sua div) não seja renderizada, apenas incluída no DOM. É um atributo explícito indicando "isto não precisa aparecer na tela".

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> A propriedade CSS  display especifica o tipo de caixa de renderização usada por um elemento. No HTML, os valores padrões da propriedade  display são feitas a partir do comportamento descrito nas especificações HTML ou da folha de estilo padrão do navegador/usuário. O valor padrão em XML é inline.
>
> Além dos muitos tipos diferentes de exibição de caixa, o valor  none permite desativar a exibição de um elemento; quando você usa none, todos os elementos descendentes também tem a sua exibição desativada. O documento é renderizado como se o elemento não existisse na árvore do documento.

Comment: E os buttons, o form e o canvas abaixo dessa div. Porque não aparacem também? Esse é o problema. dsplay: none é para não imprimir mesmo. Minha dúvida é os que estão depois dela. Porque não apareceram tb?

Comment: Por favor inclua o conteúdo do `$htmlPdf` e quaisquer CSS incluído nesta página. Se necessário, você pode criar um [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Adicionada à pergunta e https://jsfiddle.net/wv2jnydp/

Comment: Era tag div não fechada

Comment: Ótimo! Sugiro que você explique com alguns detalhes como solucionou o problema e envie como uma resposta, então marque-a como solução :)